# Storing data using async returning null because of startup error?

Tags: android, asynchronous, adapter

Would this startup error be the reason for return null everytime I save data to a sql database using ayncs?:

```
E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
```

I'm attempting to use Async and a sqlite database to store four inputs:

- Product ID
- Product Name
- Quantity
- Price

The main

I have a custom adapter which is supposed to help store then display the inputs in an array list. However, each attempt to save the inputs results in a "null" being recorded once I hit save.
Is there anything off about the way this adapter has been constructed?

BackgroundTask.JAVA

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Product, String> {
    Context ctx;
    ProductAdapter productAdapter;
    Activity activity;
    ListView listView;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx=ctx;
        activity=(Activity)ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String method = params[0];
        DbOperations dbOperations = new DbOperations(ctx);

        if(method.equals("add_info")){ // when save button it clicked, it runs backgroundTask.execute("add _info", id, name, price, quantity);
            String Id= params[1];
            String Name = params[2];
            int Price = Integer.parseInt(params[3]);
            int qty = Integer.parseInt(params[4]);
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase =dbOperations.getWritableDatabase();
            dbOperations.addInformations(sqLiteDatabase, Id, Name,Price, qty);
            return "one row inserted";
        }

        else if(method.equals("get_info")){
            listView=activity.findViewById(R.id.display_listview);
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbOperations.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = dbOperations.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
            productAdapter=new ProductAdapter(ctx, R.layout.display_product_row);
            String id, name;
            int price, qty;
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID));
                name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME));
                price = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE));
                qty = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY));
                Product product = new Product(id, name, price, qty);
                publishProgress(product);
            }
            return "get_info";
        }
        return "null";  <------ Here it's always being returned instead of saving above data
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Product... values) {
        productAdapter.add(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("get_info")){
                listView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

DisplayProduct.Java

```
public class DisplayProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_product_layout);

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute("get_info");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addProduct(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, save_info.class));
    }

    public void displayProducts(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplayProduct.class));
    }
}
```

ProductAdapter.JAVA

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public void add(Product object) {
        list.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

        @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ProductHolder productHolder;
        if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (View)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_product_row, parent, false);
        productHolder = new ProductHolder();
            productHolder.tx_id=row.findViewById(R.id.t_id);
            productHolder.tx_name=row.findViewById(R.id.t_name);
            productHolder.tx_price=row.findViewById(R.id.t_price);
            productHolder.tx_quantity=row.findViewById(R.id.t_qty);
            row.setTag(productHolder);
    }else
        {
            productHolder = (ProductHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Product product = (Product)getItem(position);
        productHolder.tx_name.setText(product.getId().toString());
        productHolder.tx_id.setText(product.getId().toString());
        productHolder.tx_price.setText(Integer.toString(product.getPrice()));
        productHolder.tx_quantity.setText(Integer.toString(product.getQty()));

    return row;
    }

    static class ProductHolder{
        TextView tx_id, tx_name, tx_price, tx_quantity;
    }
}
```

save_info.JAVA

```
public class save_info extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e_id, e_name, e_price, e_quantity;
    String id, name, price, quantity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.save_info_layout);
        e_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d_id);
        e_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d_name);
        e_price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d_price);
        e_quantity=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d_qty);

    }

    public void saveData(View view) {
        id=e_id.getText().toString();
        name=e_name.getText().toString();
        price=e_price.getText().toString();
        quantity=e_quantity.getText().toString();
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute("add _info", id, name, price, quantity);
        finish();

    }
}
```

dBOperations.JAVA

```
public class DbOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DB_NAME="product_info.db";
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "create table "+ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME+
            "("+ ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID+ " text,"+ ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME+" text,"+
            ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE+ " integer,"+ ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY+ " integer);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE="create table product_table " +
            "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "id text not null, name text not null, price integer not null, quantity  integer not null);";

    DbOperations(Context ctx){
        super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "DATABASE CREATED...");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database operations", "TABLE CREATED...");

    }

    public void addInformations(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, String id, String name, int price, int qty){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID, id);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE, price);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY, qty);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "ONE ROW INSERTED");

    }

    public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String[] projections = {ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID, ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME,
                ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE, ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY};

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME, projections,
                null, null, null, null,null );
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Include stacktrace to get more insights about error

Comment: Could this startup error be responsible for the data failing to save?
                                                          
   E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)

Comment: You have IO (FileNotFound) exception that means you are trying to access file which is not exist (or possible deleted). Please make sure file (create db first and its tables) is still there